# Content of a Button Style appears only in one Button instance

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a Viewbox:

```
<Viewbox x:Key="SampleViewbox" >
  <Grid>
    <Ellipse Stroke="#e2e2e0" StrokeThickness="6" Fill="#d5273e" Width="128" Height="128"/>
  </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

I then include this in a Style like:

```
<Style x:Key="SampleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="Transparent" >
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource SampleViewbox}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now I created many buttons with **SampleStyle**

```
<Grid>   
    <StackPanel>
       <Button Style="{StaticResource SampleStyle}" Height="50" Width="50"></Button>
       <Button Style="{StaticResource SampleStyle}" Height="80" Width="80"></Button>
       <Button Style="{StaticResource SampleStyle}" Height="20" Width="20"></Button>  
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

However, **Only one** button has the Ellipse (viewbox)

How can I make all the buttons have/show the ellipse??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Viewbox is FrameworkElement which cannot belong to multiple parents. Every time buttons request a resource `{StaticResource SampleViewbox}` they get the same instance.

to change that behavior add `x:Shared="False"` attribute

```
<Viewbox x:Key="SampleViewbox" x:Shared="False">
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. I had tried this in Kaxaml but it threw some errors. Tried it now in Visual Studio and it worked well. Are there any drawbacks of the x:Shared="False" flag?

Comment: @Sabz, drawbacks? default is `x:Shared="True"`, in most situations one doesn't want to create multiple copies of objects (e.g. brush resources, converters). but here is the opposite case, it is desired behavior

Answer (score 5):

I think a good approach is to use DataTemplate.
So you will have

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SampleViewbox">
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse
                    Width="128"
                    Height="128"
                    Fill="#d5273e"
                    Stroke="#e2e2e0"
                    StrokeThickness="6" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</DataTemplate>
```

And for style

```
<Style x:Key="SampleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="Transparent">
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SampleViewbox}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Perfect. Wish I could mark this ALSO as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the [x:Shared](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute of the `ViewBox` to `false` as suggested by @ASh will indeed work but why don't you just include the `ViewBox` in the `ControlTemplate` like this?

```
<Style x:Key="SampleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="Transparent" >
                    <Viewbox>
                        <Grid>
                            <Ellipse Stroke="#e2e2e0" StrokeThickness="6" Fill="#d5273e" Width="128" Height="128"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

A template is a template and a control instance is an instance.

Comment: For simplicity purposes, I wrote just one ellipse. In the actual case, the Viewbox contains other complex drawings. i want to use that viewbox in other styles as well..

Comment: I see, fair enough :)