# How to bind an icon to a property in XAML and C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, icons

Inside a grid, I want to display an icon based on int property DocumentType.

*This* works fine (it does display the int property DocumentType, eg 1,2 ,3, in the grid cell) :

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" MaxHeight="45" MaxWidth="45" Text="{Binding DocumentType}"/>
```

*This* does not work at all (it does not show anything in the grid cell):

```
<Path Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" MaxHeight="45" MaxWidth="45" Stretch="Uniform" Data="{Binding DocumentType, Converter={StaticResource DocumentTypeIcon}}"/>
```

Here are the resources:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <Path x:Key="Icon0" Fill="Black" Data="M12.126984,0L19.872009,0 19.872009,12.128 32,12.128 32,19.872999 19.872009,19.872999 19.872009,31.999 12.126984,31.999 12.126984,19.872999 0,19.872999 0,12.128 12.126984,12.128z" />
    <Path x:Key="Icon1" Fill="Blue" Data="M12.126984,0L19.872009,0 19.872009,12.128 32,12.128 32,19.872999 19.872009,19.872999 19.872009,31.999 12.126984,31.999 12.126984,19.872999 0,19.872999 0,12.128 12.126984,12.128z" />
    <Path x:Key="Icon2" Fill="Blue" Data="M12.126984,0L19.872009,0 19.872009,12.128 32,12.128 32,19.872999 19.872009,19.872999 19.872009,31.999 12.126984,31.999 12.126984,19.872999 0,19.872999 0,12.128 12.126984,12.128z" />
    <Path x:Key="Icon3" Fill="Red" Data="M12.126984,0L19.872009,0 19.872009,12.128 32,12.128 32,19.872999 19.872009,19.872999 19.872009,31.999 12.126984,31.999 12.126984,19.872999 0,19.872999 0,12.128 12.126984,12.128z" />
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Here is the converter:

```
public class DocumentTypeToIconConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var iDocumentType = Int32.Parse( (string) value);
            switch (iDocumentType)
            {
                case 1:
                    return Application.Current.FindResource("Icon1");
                case 2:
                    return Application.Current.FindResource("Icon2");
                case 3:
                    return Application.Current.FindResource("Icon3");
                default:
                    return Application.Current.FindResource("Icon0");
            }
        }
        return Application.Current.FindResource("Icon0");
    }
    …
}
```

It seems to me this is a pretty common use case. I tried my best to search for the solution. I am open to different suggestions, althought I understand that icons supplied as "vectors" or "path" (as shown) scale better that icons provided as png and that is my reason for prefering "path" icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding is created for Data property of type Geometry. Converter returns Path object. Type mismatch happens.

Use another control to display a path

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
      MaxHeight="45" MaxWidth="45" 
      Content="{Binding DocumentType, Converter={StaticResource DocumentTypeIcon}}"/>
```

---

there is an issue with reusing `Path` objects from resources (similar case [Content of a Button Style appears only in one Button instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42924151/content-of-a-button-style-appears-only-in-one-button-instance))

better declare Geometry as a resource

```
<Geometry x:Key="Ico" >
    M12.126984,0L19.872009,0 19.872009,12.128 32,12.128 32,19.872999 19.872009,19.872999 19.872009,31.999 12.126984,31.999 12.126984,19.872999 0,19.872999 0,12.128 12.126984,12.128z
</Geometry>
```

and use a different converter to return Brush for each document type:

```
<Path Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
      MaxHeight="45" MaxWidth="45" Stretch="Uniform" 
      Fill="{Binding DocumentType, Converter={StaticResource DocumentTypeColor}}"
      Data="{StaticResource Ico}"/>
```

```
public class DocumentTypeToColorConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var iDocumentType = Int32.Parse( (string) value);
            switch (iDocumentType)
            {
                case 1:
                case 2:
                    return Brushes.Blue;
                case 3:
                    return Brushes.Red;
                default:
                    return Brushes.Black;
            }
        }
        return Brushes.Black;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried very many different such variations before posting and your suggestion works indeed. The reason this is confusing is that the grid does not always display the icons. The converter seems to do its thing with no errors, but the grid itself does not always display the icon - I can't find a pattern. For  example if there is an icon on line 1 and more than one page is available, when I do page down and then page up to go back to the first page the icon on the first line is no longer there. It's as if the converter sometimes is too slow and does not return the data - I am confused.

Comment: That did the trick! That's a very difficult thing to find out. Thanks a lot! FYI: I simply added x:Shared="False" to each of the Path in the Resources and it worked. I did not change the converter nor the Path's to Geometry's.